# O programa deve considerar todas as validações possíveis. Isto é, não pode ser permitido acessar, deletar ou alterar uma posição inexistente da lista

Tags: python

Como colocar um comunicado de que a posição na lista está vazia e que não é possível alterar ou deletar o valor

```
import sys
lista = []
resposta = ''
continua = ''
while resposta != 'S':
    print('#### MENU ####')
    print('[L]istar')
    print('[I]nserir')
    print('[A]lterar')
    print('[D]eletar')
    print('[S]air')
    resposta = str(input('selecione uma das opcoes: '))  

    if resposta == 'I':
        numero = int(input('digite o numero: '))
        lista.append(numero)
        print('Valor adicionado com sucesso: ', lista)
        continua = str(input('deseja adicionar outro numero? '))
        while continua != 'nao':
            numero = int(input('digite o numero: '))
            lista.append(numero)
            print('Valor adicionado com sucesso: ', lista)
            continua = str(input('deseja adicionar outro numero? '))

     if resposta == 'A':
            posicao = int(input('digite a posicao: '))
            print(lista[posicao])
            lista[posicao] = int(input('digite o novo numero: '))
            print(lista)
            continua = str(input('deseja modificar outro numero? '))
            while continua != 'nao':
                posicao = int(input('digite a posicao: '))
                print(lista[posicao])
                lista[posicao] = int(input('digite o novo numero: '))
                continua = str(input('deseja modificar outro numero? '))

     if resposta == 'L':
            print('valores da lista: ', lista)

     if resposta == 'D':
         print('digite a posicao do numero que deseja excluir: ')
         posicao = int(input('digite a posicao: '))
         lista.remove(lista[posicao])
         print('valor', posicao, 'deletado com sucesso!')
         print(lista)
         continua = str(input('deseja deletar outro numero? '))
         while continua != 'nao':
             print('digite a posicao do numero que deseja excluir: ')
             posicao = int(input('digite a posicao: '))
             lista.remove(lista[posicao])
             print('valor', posicao, 'deletado com sucesso!')
             print(lista)
             continua = str(input('deseja deletar outro numero? '))

      if resposta == 'S':
          print("Saindo")

print('PROGRAMA ENCERRADO!!!!')
print(lista)
sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Poderia descrever melhor o que você deseja fazer e qual foi a dificuldade?

Comment: Colocar no programa um aviso de que a posição não se encontra no range da lista

Comment: Sim, basicamente você já disse isso na pergunta, mas digo para detalhar dizendo qual é a lista, em que momento do programa isso deve acontecer, o que ele faz, o que ele deveria fazer, etc.

Comment: a lista que será manipulada no programa, é a mesma

Comment: Olá Homero, seu código esta bem confuso, ao invés de usar if como o switch do C++, use OO e modularize o código. Nao consegui também intender muito bem sua duvida

Comment: Se for escolhida a opção "I" e a pessoa digitar 1,2,3 a lista terá como ocupadas as posições 0,1,2. Então se a pessoa quiser alterar um valor na lista ela selecionará a opção "A" e depois escolherá a posição que deseja entre a 0,1 e 2, mas se ela digitar 3 ou qlqr outra posição fora do que de fato há na lista, deve ser exibida uma mensagem "opção é inválida", pois a posição está vazia. E o mesmo vale para deletar um item.

Answer (score 0):

Use um while que repita a digitação até que o usuário digite uma posição existente:

```
while True:
    posicao = int(input('digite a posicao: '))
    if 0 <= posicao < len(lista):
        break
    print('A posição {} não existe na lista. Use um número de 0 a {}!'.format(posicao, len(lista)-1))
```

Coloque esse while toda vez que quiser ler uma posição... ou então coloque ele em uma função separada `ler_posicao()` e chame essa função toda vez que precisar ler uma posição.

Answer (score 0):

Resposta:

```
import sys
lista = []
resposta = ''
continua = ''
while resposta != 'S':
    print('#### MENU ####')
    print('[L]istar')
    print('[I]nserir')
    print('[A]lterar')
    print('[D]eletar')
    print('[S]air')
    resposta = str(input('selecione uma das opcoes: '))  

    if resposta == 'I':
        numero = int(input('digite o numero: '))
        lista.append(numero)
        print('Valor adicionado com sucesso: ', lista)
        continua = str(input('deseja adicionar outro numero? '))
        while continua != 'nao':
            numero = int(input('digite o numero: '))
            lista.append(numero)
            print('Valor adicionado com sucesso: ', lista)
            continua = str(input('deseja adicionar outro numero? '))

    if resposta == 'A':
        continua = ''
        while continua != 'nao':
            posicao = int(input('digite a posicao: '))
            if posicao == 0 or posicao <= len(lista)-1:
                print(lista[posicao])
                lista[posicao] = int(input('digite o novo numero: '))
                continua = str(input('deseja modificar outro numero? '))
            else:
                print('posicao invalida!!!!')
                continua = str(input('deseja modificar outro numero? '))
    if resposta == 'L':
        print('valores da lista: ', lista)

    if resposta == 'D':
        continua = ''
        while continua != 'nao':
            posicao = int(input('digite a posicao que deseja excluir: '))
            if posicao == 0 or posicao <= len(lista)-1:   
                lista.remove(lista[posicao])
                print('valor', posicao, 'deletado com sucesso!')
                print(lista)
                continua = str(input('deseja deletar outro numero? '))
            else:
                print('posicao invalida!!!!')
                continua = str(input('deseja deletar outro numero? '))

    if resposta == 'S':
        print("Saindo")

print('PROGRAMA ENCERRADO!!!!')
print(lista)
sys.exit(1)
```